# How to upload files using Kendo UI File Upload Control?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a simple HTML page and i would like to upload a file from client machine to server side, here i am trying to upload a file using Kendo UI contorl, but it doesn't work fine, i have given my code details below.

Included JS file is "kendo.all.min.js" and respected CSS files,

Code used for upload,

```
$("#btnUpload").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/Project1/Cifernet/upload/',
        autoUpload: false
    },
    multiple: true,
    localization: {
        select: 'Select a file',
        uploadSelectedFiles: 'Send',
        error: onError

    }
});


FYI: i got below error from Mozilla console while uploading a file.
[10:04:33.900] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  
Use defaultPrevented instead. @ http://localhost:8080/Project1/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js:3255
[10:04:34.193] GET http://localhost:8080/Project1/Styles/textures/highlight.png [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
--
[10:04:40.506] POST http://localhost:8080/Project1/upload/POST [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
[10:04:40.507] GET http://localhost:8080/Project1/Styles/Images/loading.gif [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
[10:04:40.467] "Server response: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /Project1/upload/POST</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/Project1/upload/POST</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (/Project1/upload/POST) is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.18</h3></body></html>"
[10:04:40.511] GET http://localhost:8080/Project1/Styles/textures/highlight.png [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
```

Any one Please help me to resolve this problem or please suggest best jQuery plugin with working example to upload files to the server.

Comment: You need a server-side handler that accepts the upload and then stores it - you can't simply upload a file directly to the HTTP server like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example to illustrate your problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div class="configuration">
                <span class="infoHead">Information</span>
                <p>
                    The Upload can be used as a drop-in replacement
                    for file input elements.
                </p>
                <p>
                    This "synchronous" mode does not require
                    special handling on the server.
                </p>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="submit" style="width:45%">
                <div class="demo-section">
                    <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#files").kendoUpload();
                });
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would like to save the file in the specific path, how can i do this?

Answer (score -2):

There is a good demo on the telerik site:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/async

The code below is from that demo site.

In razor your GUI code would be:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Upload")
            .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
            .AutoUpload(true)
        )
    )
```

and then you would make an Upload controller, the Save method would look like:

```
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                // We are only interested in the file name.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                // file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
            }
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

as you can see the ~/App_Data is the path to your file, which I think is what you were after.